# How can I change my (TypeScript Definition) .d.ts file to a (JavaScript) .js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, gatsby

I have found many articles on how to convert a file from .js --> .d.ts but not from .d.ts --> .js

I have this .d.ts code and I want it to be javascript code. Can anyone help?

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
export interface MapConsumerProps {
    children: (map: Map) => ReactElement | null;
}
export function MapConsumer({ children }: MapConsumerProps): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | any | (new (props: any) => import("react").Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => import("react").Component<any, any, any>)> | null;
```

In a Gatsby 2 project I found a MapConsumer element within a Leaflet MapContainer element and I don't think it is supported anymore. I want to use the code and don't know how.

```
    <MapContainer>
        <MapConsumer>
            { (map) => {

                mapRef.current = map;

                if (fitBoundCalled.current == null) {
                    map.fitBounds(sights.map(sight => [sight.node.frontmatter.lat, sight.node.frontmatter.long]))
                    fitBoundCalled.current = false;
                }

                if (mapIsVisible) {
                    map.dragging.enable();
                } else {
                    map.dragging.disable();
                }
                return null;
            } }
        </MapConsumer>
        <TileLayer/>
        <Marker/>
        </MapContainer>
```

Comment: What do you mean by converting this to Javascript code ? There is no code here, .d.ts file only contains typing and are used to make typescript aware of some existing code that does not have typing information (internal js code or external dependency)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have found a <MapConsumer> element within a Leaflet <MapContainer> element and I don't think it is supported anymore. I want to use it and don't know how.

Comment: See https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/v3/api-map/#mapconsumer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I eventually found out what I needed using the `MapContainer` and `ref={setMap}`. You don't need a `MapConsumer` after all.

Maybe the code I have pasted below will help someone else in the future who, like me, is a beginner and often confused!

```
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

        <SightsMapContainer>
                        <>
                { children } </>
        <MapContainer
            bounds={sights.map(sight => [sight.node.frontmatter.lat, sight.node.frontmatter.long])}
            minZoom={ 13 }
            maxZoom={ 18 }
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            dragging={ true }
            ref={setMap}
        >
            <TileLayer/>
            { sights.map((sight) =>
                <SightMapMarker
                    key={ sight.node.frontmatter.icon.relativeDirectory }
                    sight={ sight }
                    position={ position }
                    onMarkerClicked={ (slug) => {
                        const sight = sights.find(sight => sight.node.fields.slug === slug)
                        map.flyTo([sight.node.frontmatter.lat, sight.node.frontmatter.long])
                        onMarkerClicked(slug)
                    } }
                />) }
            </MapContainer>
        </SightsMapContainer>
```